# Is it possible for a function to be called before parameters are even set in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have this code:

```
app.get('/lights/:id', (req,res) => {
    const state = req.query.state;
    const id = req.params.id;
    hue.setLightState(id, state, function(callback){
        console.log(callback);
        res.send(callback);
    })
});
```

It's supposed to set the state of a Philips hue light by their ID based on the URL invoked and the query parameters, however it does nothing, when I `console.log` each variable (`state` and `id`) they output the right value based on what is given in the URL, so they aren't wrong.

I know it's not the function that sets the light fault as it work when I put in the values myself (it turns the light with the ID of 1 on):

```
hue.setLightState(1, true, function(callback){
    console.log(callback);
    res.send(callback);
})
```

So my assumption is that the `hue.setLightState` function is being called before the two variables `state` and `id` are even assigned a value, as there's no other explanation, is there?

EDIT (extra code on request):

App.js File:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const hue = require('./hue');

app.post('/lights/:id', (req,res) => {
    const state = req.query.state;
    const id = req.params.id;
    hue.setLightState(parseInt(id), state, function(callback){
        console.log(callback);
        res.send(callback);
    })
});

app.listen(4000, () => {console.log("Server has started")});
```

Hue.js file:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const gateway = "192.168.0.12";
const username = "username-A";

let getLights = function(callback){
    fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((json) => {
        lightsArray = []
        for (var i in json){
            lightsArray.push(`ID: ${i} Name: ${json[i]['name']}`);
        }
        return callback(lightsArray);
    });
}

let getLightDetails = function (ID, callback) {
    fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights/${ID}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
        if(res.ok){
            return res.json();
        }else{
            throw new Error(res.message);
        }
    }).then((json) => {
        return callback(json);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err.message);
    });
}

let getLightState = function(ID, callback) {
    fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights/${ID}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((json) => {
        return callback(`Name: ${json['name']} On: ${json['state']['on']}`);
    });
}

let setLightState = function (ID, state, callback) {
    fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights/${ID}/state`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({"on":state})
    }).then((res) => {
        return callback(res);
    })
}


module.exports = {getLights, getLightDetails, getLightState, setLightState};
```

As I said, the functions work, so the Hue.js file wouldn't be the problem but there it is anyway.

Boolean Switch case for debugging:

```
    switch (state){
    case true || 'true':
        console.log('its set to true');
        break;
    case false || 'false':
        console.log('its set to false');
        break;
}
```

Always outputs `its set to true`

Comment: _"there's no other explanation, is there?"_ There has to be another explanation, because this is impossible. You set your variables synchronously, and you call `hue.setLightState` immediately with those variables. Exactly as if you did `console.log`

Comment: "When I console.log state" which one? The inner or the outer?

Comment: @JaredSmith both, made sure any async calls didn't affect the output

Comment: Make sure you respect the function's signature, maybe that's it. Convert `id` to a number if it's not one, and convert `state` to a boolean if it's not one

Comment: @blex yeah, I tried that before questioning it, sorry forgot to mention, still didn't work

Comment: Is it possible that your `hue.setLightState` functions properly when the application is initialized (e.g. when your route is declared) and not in your running express app?

Comment: @drnugent Nah since when I go to the url '/lights/id:/ with the hard coded values, it still works so the functions are initalized too

Comment: Just a wild guess maybe you should parse the id since it's passed as a string

Comment: @Sven.hig Look up, we tried that I'm afraid, good guess though lmao

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example including the libraries you are using? Even without the hardware, more code would be helpful.

Comment: @Nathen can you use postman to check the values sent back ??

Comment: @drnugent sure, its basically two files using express and fetch-api

Comment: @drnugent the post was updated

Comment: @Sven.hig It's just a response back from my Philips Hue Bridge, which is expected, it does not give any useful information. It gives me `{"size":0,"timeout":0}`

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log` the URL and body in `setLightState`, is it what you expect?

Comment: I see you added the `parseInt` for the ID, but I'm convinced you're not passing a Boolean for `state`. How are you sending that parameter in the query? `?state=true`? If so, do `const state = req.body.state === "true"`

Comment: @drnugent yeah, its what I expect, everything works but that one little express app

Comment: @blex That was there on accident while testing, Ive tried all combinations of those and still doesn't work.

Comment: So just to clarify, you open the `REST` URL in your browser, and the `console.log` of the `${gateway}` URL request and payload is exactly the same as when you hardcode the values, but it just doesn't create the expected behavior?

Comment: @drnugent yes exactly, although there's an answer that partly works, it still does this behavior on setting the light back to false?

Comment: `switch` doesn't work the way you think it does. You're not making a `case` test against two options by putting two values with an `||` operator between. That will only make the `||` expression evaluate first and the `case` will test against whatever is the result of the expression. I.e. `case true || 'true':` is effectively identical to `case true:` and `case false || 'false':` effectively identical to `case 'false':`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the code that works:

```
hue.setLightState(1, true, function(callback){
```

And the one that didn't:

```
hue.setLightState(parseInt(id), state, function(callback){
```

The only difference is about the conversion of the `state` variable. You should convert it to a boolean.

Converting the `id` variable is innocuous, since it is converted back to a string when building the URL:

```
fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights/${ID}/state`, {
```

But the `state` variable will be serialized as JSON:

```
    body: JSON.stringify({"on":state})
```

So your body is probably being submitted as:

```
{"on":"true"}
```

When it should be:

```
{"on":true}
```

Comment: I swear this is out to get me?! I hate JS hahah, although that fixed my issue partly - I can only use it to set the light to on (true), I can't do the opposite and set it to false (off). Why is that?

Comment: You should check your boolean conversion. I'd recommend writing a custom one, something like this (pseudocode): `switch(value){case 'true','True','T',1,'1','on': return true; default: false }`

Comment: BTW, reading the comments, @blex told you to convert `state` to a boolean about 30mins earlier than my answer.

Comment: Yeah, and I even repeated it _"I'm convinced you're not passing a Boolean for state"_ and @Nathan answered _"Ive tried all combinations of those and still doesn't work."_  I upvoted your answer btw

Comment: @FábioBatista and as I stated, the two combined doesn't work, it still doesn't work now it's just always setting it to true, even with switching through the values as you recommended.

Comment: @Nathan, please update the question with your boolean conversion logic, then.

Comment: ... and the format of the queryString you're sending (`?state=true` / `?state=false` ?)

Comment: Did some debugging, I still have the same issue as I had in the beginning as adding Boolean(state) to the function's arguments defaults to true and only sends true as it is not getting the correct values from the URL.

Comment: The only way to get a `false` from a string with a `Boolean(...)` call is to pass an empty string. Every other string, even the string `'false'` will convert to `true`. That's why I recommended a custom conversion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: Your `switch` syntax is wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @FábioBatista I cant see which part is wrong? Either way, the switching does nothing, the value coming through will still be incorrect.

Comment: @Nathan `hue.setLightState(id, state === "true", function...` and you're done